# RichFaces 4 autocomplete is not showing suggestions

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces, client-side, facelets

I am trying for too long to make an autocomplete custom suggestion demo.
The demo is partially working as I can see the suggestions response in f12 debugger, but it is not showing in the drop down box.
I am doing the following

POM:

```
 <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <org.richfaces.version>4.3.3.Final</org.richfaces.version>

</properties>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>org.openfaces</id>
        <url>http://repository.openfaces.org/repository</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>jfree</id>
        <url>http://www.ibiblio.org/maven/jfree/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.richfaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>richfaces-bom</artifactId>
        <version>${org.richfaces.version}</version>
        <scope>import</scope>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.richfaces.ui</groupId>
        <artifactId>richfaces-components-ui</artifactId>
        <version>${org.richfaces.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.richfaces.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>richfaces-core-impl</artifactId>
        <version>${org.richfaces.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

the bean:

```
    @ManagedBean    
    @RequestScoped
    public class TagCollector  implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4930140495481611695L;
    String tagName;
    public Converter getTagNameConverter(){
        return new Converter() {

            @Override
            public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent converter, Object value) {
                System.out.println("getAsString=" +(String)value);
                return (String)value;
            }

            @Override
            public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent converter, String value) {
                System.out.println("getAsObject=" +value);
                return value;
            }
        };
    }

    public List<String> getSuggestedTags(){
        String searchString = Faces.var("searchString", String.class);
        System.out.println("getSuggestedTags searchString="+ searchString);
        List<String> suggestedTags = Arrays.asList(new String[]{"ford", "mazda", "fiat"});
        return suggestedTags;   
    }

    public String getTagName() {
        return tagName;
    }

    public void setTagName(String tagName) {
        this.tagName = tagName;
    }
   }
```

the xhtml:

```
    <h:form>
        <h:outputText value="Enter state" />
        <rich:autocomplete mode="ajax" minChars="1" showButton="true"
            autocompleteMethod="#{userBean.autocomplete}">
</rich:autocomplete>
    </h:form>
```

the faces config:

```
<managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>tagCollector</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>org.taagad.tag.model.TagCollector</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope> 
</managed-bean>
```

I really search the web for hours getting nowhere, any idea will be helpful.

Comment: If you can see the `<div>` containing the suggestions in the code but not on the page then the problem is in CSS or JavaScript. What does the autocomplete method do?

Comment: There is not css as I use default style in this test so it can not be css issue. the autocomplete just returns list of car manufacturers the the user will be able to set as tags.
The issue is certainty in the client side since I do see the data on the wire.

Comment: The solution was to use JSF 2.1.25

Comment: And what have you used before? RF4 is not compatible with JSF 1.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this issue! it is working on jsf 2.1.25.
Same issue was with RichFaces, it appears both implementations are sensitive to the same issue/bug with jsf iml and api.
That's the pom on my project:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.25</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.25</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.portlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>portlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```