# Richfaces - <rich:autocomplete> not showing suggestions

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, richfaces

I'm having problems with autocomplete not showing suggestions. Not sure what I'm missing. The code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich">
  <h:head />
  <h:body>
    <h:form>
      <rich:autocomplete autocompleteMethod="#{myBean.autocomplete}" var="item">
    <h:outputText value="#{item}" />
      </rich:autocomplete>
    </h:form>
  </h:body>
</html>
```

and

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class MyBean {
    public List<String> autocomplete(FacesContext ctx, UIComponent c, String prefix) {
        return Arrays.asList(new String[] {"foo", "bar", "baz"});
    }
}
```

The bean method gets invoked when I type and I can see an AJAX POST return results in the browser console:

```
<!-- ... snip ... -->
<componentData>{"j_idt5:j_idt6":["for","bar","baz"] }</componentData>
```

However the suggestions do not get displayed. Any ideas?

Using JSF 2 and Richfaces 4.3.4 deployed on JBoss WildFly 8.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this is a known issue ([RF-13587](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/RF-13587)). It can be resolved by using JSF version 2.1.25 as described here:

[RichFaces 4 autocomplete is not showing suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18499184)